# Just like a WI??O?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a single word.

---

[image]

 [image]

[image]

Comment: Looks cool. May be a dumb question, but do the tiny white stars and dashes on the borders of the red squares mean anything for the puzzle? Or can they be ignored?

Comment: @JLee No not intentional, just ignore them

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://i.imgur.com/Z6jKj58.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word is:

> Reflection

Because:

> The second image is a grid of mirrors/walls that reflect a ball sent in from the left (hinted at by the first image):
>  [image: 4x4 grid of squares, some half filled with diagonal mirrors]

> The third image can be divided into a four-by-four grid of squares, each of which is a 3x3 pixel font letter. And reading those in the order of squares that the ball crosses gives us the answer:
>  [image: 4x4 grid of pixel font letters]

And the title:

> Hints (if we reflect it vertically) that the answer is just like a MIRROR!

Comment: What's going on with the R, the T and the N? The T and N are upside down, and the R is just a backwards L when looking from the other side. The rest of the letters look correct when looking from the other side (flipping along vertical axis). btw +1. I didn't know there was a 3x3 pixel font!

Comment: @JLee I think the letters should be viewed/reflected based on the direction the ball is travelling, but couldn't quite work out a consistent explanation.

Comment: @JLee Looking at it again, a simpler explanation may be that the letters in the bottom half are also reflected vertically. (Not that you can tell with the I and O)

Comment: Wow. Good observation. I never considered that

Comment: Well done! Let me add some explanations, rot13(Gurl nyy ner rvgure ubevmbagny BE iregvpny ersyrpgvbaf. Gur fgnegvat yrggre, E, V pbhyq'ir znqr vg n ubevmbagny ersyrpgvba fb gung vg qvqa'g ybbxrq yvxr na Y, ohg fgvyy gur bayl ersyrpgvba gung jbhyq tvir n yrtvg yrggre nsgrejneqf jbhyq or vs lbh iregvpnyyl ersyrpgrq vg. Ernfba orvat V jnagrq gurz gb npghnyyl ybbx qvssrerag sebz gurve npghny fgngr. Fb jura V jnf noyr gb qb gung - V qvq fb. Sbe rknzcyr R,iregvpnyyl ersyrpgrq, vf fgvyy na R. Fnzr jvgu P. S pbhyq or rvgure. Y pbhyq or rvgure...

Comment: ...G naq A, iregvpnyyl bayl, be ryfr gurl'q ybbx gur fnzr. Naq nf lbh zragvbarq V naq B lbh fvzcyl pna'g gryy ertneqyrff vs gurl'er ubevmbagnyyl be iregvpnyyl ersyrpgrq.